# Using an array of users with update_user_meta

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the following code which updates the current user logged in:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'wasc_coupon', 'yes');
```

I would like the above meta to be updated for all current registered users. Is it a simple case of storing the user id's into array and doing something like this?

```
update_user_meta($userArray, 'wasc_coupon', 'yes');
```

Or does the `update_user_meta` not support multiple users / arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the update_user_meta do not suport arrays of users.. only int values...

but, u can make a for to make this...

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($userArray); $i++) {
    update_user_meta($userArray[$i], 'wasc_coupon', 'yes');
}
```